# Unable to get the window title

Tags: c++, winapi

I am unable to get the window title of the Skype. The following code returns an empty string:

```
std::wstring get_window_title(HWND hwnd)
{
  wchar_t window_title[256];
  SendMessageW(hwnd, WM_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)256, (LPARAM)window_title);
  return window_title;
}
```

Window's handle is valid.

Am I using this function incorrectly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of window are you sending the WM_GETTEXT to?

Comment: @Greycon What do you want to know about this window? This is the regular Skype window. Should I tell you the class or styles of this window?

Comment: Well, it says the window handle is invalid. So, have you verified (debugging vs. for instance Spy++) that you are indeed using the correct window handle?

Comment: Have you checked GetLastError() ?

Comment: @MicroVirus Yep, I directly use the handle that I've got from the Spy++. btw I just noticed that this problem appears not only in case of Skype

Comment: @Greycon GetLastError function returns 0

Comment: In the case that you are not the owning process, the behaviour is as follows: " If the target window is owned by another process and has a caption, GetWindowText retrieves the window caption text. If the window does not have a caption, the return value is a null string. " Perhaps this is why you are getting a null string?

Comment: @Greycon That's for `GetWindowText`, not for `WM_GETTEXT`

Comment: Maybe I need to user VirtualAlloc? Or SendMessage function do this for me?

Comment: @MicroVirus, GetWindowText sends WM_GETTEXT to the specified window.

Comment: @Greycon Yes but it does more than that, namely exactly what you specified in your comment, but that's not relevant here, because this is the case of directly sending the message.

Comment: @MicroVirus, OK, I bow to your superior knowledge! It's been many a year since I worked with WM_ stuff. :-)

Comment: @MicroVirus Dynamically on the stack? I think that you mean new statement, am I right? If so, nothing happens

Comment: Why would you call `GetLastError`. The documentation makes no indication that would be useful. What you are not doing is checking the value returned by `SendMessage`.

Comment: Yeah I meant on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and could not reproduce the issue. The issue is not in the piece of code you have shown, rather in the acquiring of the window handle. I suggest we vote to close this post, and you can ask a new question regarding the window handle.

For the record, I tested both with `SendMessage` and `GetWindowText`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works fine, modulo the fact that you don't check for errors. You need to check the value returned by `SendMessageW`. This return value indicates how many characters were copied to your buffer.

The most likely explanation for the code to fail when you run it is that you are supplying an invalid or incorrect window handle.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like I need to use GlobalAlloc function in this situation.

Comment: -1 This is not the case. It doesn't matter how the memory is allocated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Out of interest, am I correct in assuming this is because behind the scenes `SendMessage` knows about the `WM_GETTEXT` message and handles the allocation of a temporary shared buffer for the window text to be pasted in, which is then copied into the user specified buffer before returning?

Comment: @Micro Correct. System understood messages are marshalled cross-process, if needed. But user-defined messages are not, for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -2):

Try [`GetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520(v=vs.85).aspx), which can get around some of the difficulties of trying to send a message to a window in another process.

`WM_GETTEXT` asks the other process to write to a buffer that's in your address space rather than its own, which is not feasible.  A few messages will marshal such buffers between process address spaces, but I don't think `WM_GETTEXT` is one of them.

**UPDATE**:  It's been suggested in the comments that `WM_GETTEXT` is one of the messages that will marshal a string between process address spaces.  I haven't found an authoritative source for that, and have found many non-authoritative posts claiming both that it does and does not.  Regardless, `GetWindowText` is documented to work for non-child windows in other processes, so it's still a viable solution to the problem.

Comment: -1 you are incorrect, the system marshals this message.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Do you have a link to which messages Windows will marshal the data for?  I recently read a partial list (which didn't include WM_GETTEXT), and I've been looking for a definitive one.  Since the docs for GetWindowText says that it does _not_ use WM_GETTEXT across processes, I took that as a hint that WM_GETTEXT isn't marshaled.

Comment: I don't know of a list. Certainly this one is marshalled. It's easy to check.

Comment: The confusion around this function/Window-message is not entirely unjust: a good read from The Old New Thing: [The secret life of GetWindowText](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx). Also, I think it was on MSDN that I read that USER32 does all necessary marshalling for all messages up to WM_USER-1 (and The Old New Thing article says so too).

Comment: @MicroVirus:  Thanks for the Old New Thing reference.  I'd certainly read that article in the past, but I missed the implication that all system-defined messages do marshaling.  I swear I'd read somewhere that only a select few do.  I still maintain that `GetWindowText` is worth trying in this instance, since it specifically avoids some of the potential pitfalls of sending a window message between processes, like UIPI.

Comment: @Adrian for getter messages UIPI does not apply. If you only ran the code, or accepted my doing so, but the WM_GETTEXT message does work cross process and does get the Skype window caption.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Why wouldn't UIPI apply to "getter" messages?  I've got WM_GETTEXT working across processes when both processes are at medium level integrity.  But if I lower the sender process to low integrity, it stops working.  Meanwhile, GetWindowText continues to work, even called from a low integrity process.  MSDN documentation says flat out:  "A lower privilege process cannot SendMessage or PostMessage to higher privilege application windows."  Apps can set their message filter to allow exceptions, but I don't see anything about a blank exception for "getter" messages.

Comment: Strange.  That's not consistent with my experiment.  If I set the sender process to Low Integrity, the WM_GETTEXT silently fails but GetWindowText still works.  Tested on Windows 7.